# Mongodb Convention packs

Tags: c#, mongodb

How does one use a MongoDB `ConventionPack` in C# I have the following code:

```
MongoDatabase Repository = Server.GetDatabase(RepoName);
this.Collection = Repository.GetCollection<T>(CollectionName);
var myConventions = new ConventionPack();
myConventions.Add(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());
```

Does the convention pack automatically attach to this.Collection? 
 When I load in a new object will it automatically persist it as this case? 
 Do I have to add tags in my class declaration (like a data contract)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to register the pack in the `ConventionRegistry`:

```
var pack = new ConventionPack();
pack.Add(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());
ConventionRegistry.Register("camel case",
                            pack,
                            t => t.FullName.StartsWith("Your.Name.Space."));
```

If you want to apply this globally, you can replace the last param with something simpler like `t => true`.

Working sample code that serializes and de-serializes (driver 1.8.20, mongodb 2.5.0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Conventions;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace playground
{
    class Simple
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Counter { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost/test");
            var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase("test");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<Simple>("Simple");
            var pack = new ConventionPack();
            pack.Add(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());
            ConventionRegistry.Register("camel case", pack, t => true);
            collection.Insert(new Simple { Counter = 1234, Name = "John" });
            var all = collection.FindAll().ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + all[0].Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the edit that helps. You may have noticed I asked both of these questions. Does this apply the convention whenever I add a new document?

Comment: Yes, this will apply the convention whenever the serializer reads or writes a document. Make sure to register the convention early, e.g. after creating the database object.

Comment: no, you shouldn't need that. All *properties* will be automatically (de-)serialized.

Comment: It doesn't appear to work that way if the DB fields are camelCase and the c# fields are PascalCase

Comment: It does, I do have a working sample application here (driver 1.8.1.20, mongodb 2.5.0). What ends up in the database after serialization?

Comment: A camel case representation is persisted into the database but it there is an exception when I try to deserialize it that says no field matches it

Comment: I found that in order for camel-casing to work correctly, I needed to call `ConventionRegistry.Register()` _before_ instantiating my collection (e.g. `db.GetCollection<TDocument>()`). Otherwise I got mixed results/strange behavior.

Comment: I confirm. If collection of particular type is already created then registration of a new convention pack takes no effect.