# MongoDB C# Driver Saves Empty Properties

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I have a C# object with about 500 properties, some of them complex types. The Json documents are imported via XML and it works 100%. I can also query the collection and successfully serialize the Json document into the C# object. The problem is that when I make a change to the object and use collection.Save(object); it creates Json properties for ALL of the C# properties even though they are NULL, so now my document looks like this:

```
    { 
    "_id" : "AA00001", 
    "Product" : {
        "Reference" : "AA00001", 
        "Type" : "02", 
        "Code" : null, 
        "Property 1" : null, 
        "Property 2" : null, 
        "Property 3" : null, 
    .
    .
    .   
}
```

The original document looked like this before the C# save

```
{ 
"_id" : "AA00001", 
"Product" : {
    "Reference" : "AA00001", 
    "Type" : "02"
.
.
.
```

Is there a way to tell the driver not to save the empty/null values?

Thank you.

Comment: The null values are saved because that's how the model looks, if you try to load a data from MongoDB which doesn't match the model the MongoDB driver will throw an exception.. That's my experience..

Comment: Hi Martin, I have the [IgnoreExtraElements] attribute on my classes, so it only pulls in what matches.

Comment: Hey, there are like several dozen questions I've found that ask how to do what you did. You might be able to farm up some points by answering them. I'm having an issue doing what you did here. I have a single field on a class model that needs to accept anything and everything I can throw at it, but it never seems to serialize correctly. Got any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by registering a ConventionPack:

```
var pack = new ConventionPack();
pack.Add(new IgnoreIfNullConvention(true));
ConventionRegistry.Register("ignore nulls",
                            pack,
                            t => true);
```

`IgnoreIfNull` will prevent the fields from being serialized. There's also a `IgnoreIfDefaultConvention` which also works for value types.

For more Details on how to register these, you might want to refer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521626/mongodb-convention-packs) here on SO.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at this.