# MongoDB: How can I register conventions with Mongo 2.0

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am initializing the MongoClient in this way:

```
var client = new MongoClient(MongoConnectionString)
```

But how can I explain it that it should use the convention classes I've defined?

I've put them inside a class named `BsonClassMap`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before defining other BsonClassMaps you can configure your convention for all classes

Example:

```
var conventionPack = new ConventionPack();
conventionPack.Add(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());
ConventionRegistry.Register("camelCase", conventionPack, t => true);
```

**Note**: `t => true` means for all, but you can configure to use only for namespaces, etc..

Comment: But how do I associate them with the MongoClient? Mongo will understand that I want to use this conventions?

Comment: @Revious This is applied globally. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521626/mongodb-convention-packs