# Is this what BsonElement and ElementName for in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Based on my [reading](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/serialization/), they are only used in serialization and deserialization. While most of the time we rely on MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes and the so-called "automap" to translate, say

```
{
public string Property_1 {get; set;}
public string Property_2 {get; set;}
...
}
```

are actually correspondingly stored in as "**p1**" and "**p2**" inside of MongoDB.

But now I want to twist the mapping (link) to 
**Property_1 <-> p2** and **Property_2 <-> p1**
I then will do

```
{
[BsonElement(elementName = "p2")]
public string Property_1 {get; set;}
[BsonElement(elementName = "p1")]
public string Property_2 {get; set;}
...
}
```

Right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Why are you doing this? I wonder if there's a better way, depending on your use case.

Comment: @john I was wondering why there so many sample codes have them

Comment: My point is that if you simply want to camelCase all property names, for example, you could use a ConventionPack instead.

Comment: @john what is ConventionPack for?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521626/mongodb-convention-packs)